# STS/Eclipse error: Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources"

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, annotation-processing

I've written a custom annotation and processor which implements `com.sun.source.util.TaskListener`.
The annotation processing currently works when ran as part of a gradle build, but when I enable annotation processing in STS, I get the following error:

```
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources"

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/source/util/TaskListener
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.internal.AnnotationProcessorFactoryLoader.loadJava6FactoryClasses(AnnotationProcessorFactoryLoader.java:638)
at org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.internal.AnnotationProcessorFactoryLoader.loadFactories(AnnotationProcessorFactoryLoader.java:577)
at org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.internal.AnnotationProcessorFactoryLoader.getJava6FactoriesAndAttributesForProject(AnnotationProcessorFactoryLoader.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.dispatch.IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processAnnotations(Compiler.java:968)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:397)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:184)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:334)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:63)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:256)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:180)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.source.util.TaskListener
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 35 more
```

I've tried a few things to try to resolve this:

- I have changed the installed JRE to point to an installed JDK
- I added tools.jar as an external jar in the JRE Definition in eclipse
- I tried adding tools.jar as an external jar to the project on which annotation processing has been turned on.
- I also tried adding tools.jar as a defined Classpath variable

Answer (score 0):

`com.sun.source.util.TaskListener` is javac-private API. Eclipse has it's own compiler. Try to set the default compiler to Javac in Eclipse settings.

Comment: Its certainly an option, though I was hoping to be able to be able to use the my annotation processor with the incremental eclipse compiler.

Comment: I think The Checker Framework must have the same problem, which is probably why they have an Eclipse plugin. Project Lombok handles Eclipse specific behavior by some sort of ClassLoader magic (Again: I speculate, I am no expert. Just thinking about alternative ways to solve this. The best would off course be if these internal APIs were made an official part of Java specification).